# Subprocess with ruby

Tags: ruby

I try to find the good way to call subprocess with ruby.I want to launch a new second terminal with a commande inside and then execute a new command after the last one on the first terminal.I want to do the same in ruby like this python short code.

```
import os
import subprocess
htop = "x-terminal-emulator -e 'bash -c \"htop; exec bash\"'"
ls = "ls"
p = subprocess.Popen(htop, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p1 = subprocess.Popen(ls, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

here htop is started on second terminal and then ls on the first, with ruby im stuck at htop and after ls is not started.Here is my ruby code

```
stdout, stdeerr, status = Open3.capture3("x-terminal-emulator -e bash -c htop")
sleep 2
system "iwconfig wlan0"
```

Comment: `Open3.capture3` is synchronous, while `subprocess.Popen` is asynchronous. The equivalent of Python's `subprocess.Popen` is `Open3.popen3`. Your example is kind of short, I can't see what you're doing with `p` and `p1`, so I can't really offer more than this comment.

Comment: P and p1 mean print.What i want is do the same as python, the python code start htop from the first terminal to the second and then execute ls command on the first terminal.If i try this with my ruby code i got stuck at htop and after my second command is never executed.The objective is start an automous terminal and then come back to the first and execute the next command.

Comment: `p` and `p1` can't mean `print` because they are variables being assigned return value from `subprocess.Popen`, and it does not return a function. And in Ruby code you invoke `system "iwconfig wlan0"`, which has nothing to do with what you had in your Python code. In your answer, you're using `sleep 2`, which is not found in your Python code, and will probably do unexpected things is the first process takes longer than that. To get the best answer on Stack Overflow, it would be best to ask questions that actually make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using fork

```
fork { exec "x-terminal-emulator -e bash -c htop" }
sleep 2
    system "ls"
```

I will come back soon im learning ruby.